# Mitsubishi lancer 2003

Tags: mitsubishi

is it ok to shift from 95 octane to 91 octane? as my car is suitable to use 91 octane only..but because of ignorance we use 95 octane from the start until now.my car is a 2003 mitsubishi lancer 1.3..
Thanks

Comment: Your fine.  don't worry about.  It will not hurt your car at all.  It's what's called for by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to use 91.

Comment: yeah, that's what the maker reccomends!

Answer (score 0):

If Mitsubishi say the engine's designed to run on 91 octane then it's fine to put that in it. Using 95 octane will only harm your wallet as it's usually more expensive than 91 octane, it won't have any effect on the engine.